# Sentinel-2 unable to handle this request

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel-hub

I have been utilising the API Hub to access Sentinel-2 data. The script I am using is from the Sentinelsat documentation [here](https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and has worked for all images I have required except for S2B_MSIL2A_20220304T002709_N0400_R016_T55KCV_20220304T022405. I have attempted to manually use the open access hub interface and other 3rd party websites such as, https://mundiwebservices.com/data/sentinel-2 or https://www.sentinel-hub.com/explore/eobrowser/ but either nothing happens or I get the following error for that file only. This file is NOT offline, it is only 6 months old so it should not have been archived yet.

> **This page isn’t working** 
> ***scihub.copernicus.eu*** is currently unable to handle this request. 
> *HTTP ERROR 500*

This is the file I want. You can see from this it is not offline.

I need this specific region during this point in time, and there are no other images of this tile with sufficiently low cloud cover etc, so can you help in retrieving this specific image?

[image: Desired Image]

Comment: If you can find it in the webinterface of the Copernicus Open Access Hub - is there a reason you can't download it from there? For a single image that would arguably be easier then using a Python library.

Comment: @Kersten I initially utilized the API Hub because it was apart of a group of images I wanted. When it failed I then tried with both the Copernicus Open Access Hub and the API Hub to acquire that specific image. I don't know why it would fail, I have never had this happen for any other image and the only information I got was the error above.